# What does servicing the Regalia do?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I decided to humor Cindy by having her service the Regalia for a change. To my dismay, I paid her a ton of Gil and saw no change in performance or appearance. What exactly did I pay her to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can damage Regalia during driving. Usually service removes all possible consequences (such as damaged appearance). It also cleans car.

Comment: Is that really it? Doesn't changing paint jobs or decals do the same thing?

Comment: @Vemonus I can tell you that changing your paint or decals does not fix your car. I had a situation where I busted up my car pretty badly, didn't have enough money to service and my car was still busted up after I customized my car.

Comment: @Ramirez oh, really? That's odd. When I finally removed the Leviathan decal, it seemed like my car looked good as new. Maybe it's because it was a decal?

Comment: @Vemonus Was your car damaged? Cause I know that Cindy does clean the car when you change your car's look. I remember having a picture of my car freshly customized that looked like my car drove through a war zone.

Comment: @Ramirez how exactly does your car get damaged? Mine looked dinged up and it was *definitely* dirty, but it may just not have been damaged.

Comment: When you are driving you can do slight manual control, I kinda maybe got Ignis to drive headlong into another car coming at me. I learned my lesson and just let Ignis drive for me after that.

Comment: @Ramirez I tried so hard to run into other cars but the combination of how slow I was driving and how quickly they braked prevented me, so I just assumed it wasn't possible. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Vemonus While running into another car I had my windscreen being full of cracks. As far I can remember customizing the car couldn't fix it, so I had to pay the 500 gils. I don't know about the damages on the rest of the car itself though, so you might be right on this.

Comment: @Vemonus you can damage it if you drive into a t shaped intersection and hit the railing.  You have to hit it perpendicular.  Sometimes if you reverse the car in a super tight road it will hit the railing.  At night you might get attacked by iron giants.  He will run towards you and if the poor regalia is in the way the ole girl will get kicked 10 feet in the air.  If you damage the car badly enough you will see a red triangle and see a noticeable speed reduction.  Take it to Cindy and she will fix it for a price.

Answer (score 1):

It repairs the Regalia as well as cleaning any mud off of it!

However, it's worth noting that you can upgrade the Regalia to be more durable by completing Cindy's missions and getting the fiberglass coating.

Later in the game in Altissia, you can purchase the Superhydrophobic coating (which does the same, only better) for 20,000 gil.